# Scroll in an activity

Tags: android

I have an `EditText`, `Spinner`, `RadioButton` and `Checkbox` in an activity. So I need a `ScrollView` in that activity programmatically without using XML.

How can i create scrollview programmatically without using XML?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working? And why the restriction on doing in programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create the ScrollView
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

//Get the base layout for your Activity and add the scroll view to it.
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.content);
root.addView(scroll);

//Add your layout here which contains the EditText, Spinner and RadioButton and CheckBox.
scroll.addView(yourExistingLayout);
```